# opens archive insted of downloading it

Tags: ftp, download, archive

i have a simple question, but i couldn't find an easy solution for it, i have a rented ftp, i cant moderate it, and i have a website with links to this ftp, there few archive files that i want them to be downloaded rather than opened directly through browser, my link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://ftp.micae.com/micae/dvr/yazilimlar/IMS_200.rar" target="_blank">IMS 200 Client V1.29 (06.02.13)</a>
```

i solved this problem by using php page that defines the file type, so that browser could understand that it is archive, and then download it, rather than try and open it directly through browser, is there any easier way to achieve it?!

thank u all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that my case can help you some way.
I have a website that allows user to view news and download files. Oneday, I discover that if I show up the download link to a .rar file directly, eg. http://www.somenet.com/myfile.rar, then it is opened automatically in the browser instead of asking users if they want to save/open it. If I write some code to read and transfer the file to browser, eg. http://www.somenet.com/download?fileid=123, then it is asked to be saved/opened by browser.

After googling a while, I insert a piece of configuration into my Apache Tomcat web.xml (often at CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml) as follows:

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>rar</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-rar-compressed</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

then restart the Apapche Tomcat server to take effect.

And now i can click on the direft rar link to download the file.

I also have to restart the IE (FF takes effect right away).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5 you can try to use:

```
<a href="path/to/file/file.png" download="a-nice-image.png">Download this file</a>
```

Extracted from: [HTML5 link download](http://drublic.de/blog/offer-files-as-download-with-adownload/)